# Selenium and Spring Failed to invoke @Configuration method

Tags: spring, selenium, testng

I am new to all this and setting it up has been a bit overwhelming. I am using ant to run a bunch of tests using testng suites.

It gets to a point where I receive this error:

`[testng] Failed to invoke @Configuration method org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance:Error creating bean with name 'com.mystuffs.tests1.CreateTest1': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.mystuffs.web.BrowserTest1.setBrowser(com.mystuffs.web.browser.Browser); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'browser' defined in class path resource [applicationcontext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser`

It looks like a dependency issue of some sort, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: It would help us if you gave us your ant code as well.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you try: the problem is that you try to instanciate a Selenium Browser Session while starting your Application and this failes:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

So you should have a look why selenium can not launch the browser